# Opportunity for a good tool/service

Tags: soft-question

is there an opportunity for a good tool (web/win/linux), which would help to construct/display math equations (expression trees), handle table formulas, mixtures of logical & math operands, help to debug and model processes? Sorry for being too broad but I'm looking for any suggestions. How would you rank the futures for that tool actuality/priority wise?

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "opportunity." Do you mean whether there is a demand for such a thing? But there are already many such things (although I am not sure what you mean by "debug and model processes").

Comment: Hi, you're right demand is the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Windows platform at least, there is certainly a *need* for custom controls that know how to render latex and/or mathml. I recently did a fairly exhaustive search for exactly that and was rather shocked to dicover that there was absolutely *nothing* that would do the job. Specifically, if you built a native WPF/Silverlight widget that was was capable of rendering latex/mathml it would certainly fill a gap because at present, as far as I know, nothing like this exists. Yes, there are custom applications of course that do this such as Mathematica, Maple etc. but nothing that can be reused by an ISV to build their own math-oriented applications.

Comment: 3Sphere@ Thanks very much for that.

Comment: Mind me asking - talking about LaTeX/MathML support - which one would you choose if you could only choose one?

Comment: I would choose latex support simply because its (substantially)more concise, less complicated and well-known. Mathml really only becomes an issue when interoperating with other tools/systems. A human can write latex easily, I can't say the same for mathml.